# How do I pass parameter to an angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made simple HTTP based API  and I would like to make POST calls to it like:

```
http://mysite.com/api/v1/person/something
http://mysite.com/api/v1/person/else
http://mysite.com/api/v1/person/someword
```

in general

```
http://mysite.com/api/v1/person/<word>
```

In angular I have created a service

```
angular.module('personService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Person', function($resource){
      return $resource('/api/v1/person/:word', {}, {
        action:     {method:'{POST',  params:{ ???? },          isArray : false},
      });
  });
```

And in my controller which uses the service I would like to be able to call `Person.action()` and pass it a parameter to determine what `word` is, for example:

```
Person.action('something', function(d) { 
 console.log('Result of api/v1/person/something')
});
```

but I'm not sure how to connect the two. See `????` in the third code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
params:{ word: '@inputWord' }

Person.action({inputWord: 'somethings'}, function(d) { 
    console.log('Result of api/v1/person/something')
});
```

`word` matches the `:word` variable in the url and the passed in object's key `inputWord` matches `@inputWord`.